# Customize Domain on Hybris site

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, tomcat9

We have a application built on Hybris 2205 OCC along with Spartacus 4. The requirement is to customize the default site url ie from https://localhost:9002 to https://localhost:9002/mySite . Usually Hac gets loaded with https://localhost:9002 but with this requirement it should get loaded with https://localhost:9002/mySite & similarly
Backoffice https://localhost:9002/mySite/backoffice. We have tried with couple of changes at tomcat configuration but nothing seems to be working as files gets reloaded with ant clean. Kindly provide your valuable inputs and help us to resolve the issue.

Comment: Did you try hac.webroot config parameter?

Comment: This is easier to be configured by a DevOps using nginx, for example: redirecting all the requests from https://localhost:9002/mySite to https://localhost:9002. And, if you've found a solution by changing the tomcat configuration, you should make use of the `ant customize` command (which will help you with the reloading issue) by adding the customized configuration file in the `hybris_platform/hybris/config/customize` folder.

Comment: @use We tried changing server.xml , config.xml but changes got overwritten with ant clean. Could you please suggest what kind of configuration to be included within /customize folder.

Comment: The path of the `server.xml` and `config.xml` is the following: `hybris_platform/hybris/bin/platform/tomcat/conf...`. What you need to do is to create the same folder structure within the `customize` folder where you add the modified xml files. For example, you can create the following: `../customize/platform/tomcat/conf` where you add the modified `server.xml` & `config.xml` and run an `ant customize` & `ant clean all`